# Recoding in R; recode if

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that is like this:

```r
a <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,0,9,9,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,9)
b <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,1,9,9,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,9)
c <- c(NA,NA,FALSE,NA,FALSE,NA,NA,NA,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

If column c is false I want to turn the 9s in columns a and b into NA.

Otherwise if column c is true I want to leave the 9s as 9. How can I do this please in R? I tried an ifelse but it also turns the 9 into NA when column c is TRUE.

```r
ifelse(df$c == 'FALSE', df[df == 9] <- NA , 9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `across` and `case_when()`, e.g.

```
 library(dplyr)
  df %>%
  mutate(across(
    c(a, b),
    ~ case_when(
      (!d & . == 9) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ .
    )
  ))
```

**Output:**

```
     a    b     d
1  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
2  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
3     1    1 FALSE
4  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
5     0    0 FALSE
6  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
7  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
8  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
9     0    1 FALSE
10    9    9  TRUE
11    9    9  TRUE
12 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
13 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
14 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
15 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
16 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
17 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
18    0    0 FALSE
19 <NA> <NA> FALSE
```

**Data:**

```
a <- c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 9, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 9)
b <- c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 9, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 9)
d <- c(
  NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE,
  TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE
)

df <- data.frame(a, b, d)
```

Comment: `d` is a logical vector. Don't use `d == "FALSE"` to identify it because that will convert `d` into character before determining equality. You should use `(!d & . == 9) ~ NA_character_`

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the explanation @DarrenTsai, I will edit it!

Comment: I edit your post to revise how you reproduce the data. Keep in mind that don't quote `TRUE` and `FALSE` because that will make them character, not logical. And don't use `as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))` to create a dataframe if a,b,c have different types. `cbind` will convert all columns into the same type.